# How to let an overlayarea appear in the beamer mode?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I basically have the following code for one frame

```
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{VERY INTELLIGENT FRAME TITLE}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics<1->[scale=.23]{PICTURE1.PDF}
\begin{center}
\tiny{\quad\qquad\text{VERY FAMOUS PAPER}}
\end{center}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics<2->[scale=.23]{PICTURE2.PDF}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{.5cm}
\small
\begin{align} \nonumber 
*EQUATION*
\end{align}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
```

So I would like to let the equation appear with the second picture. I tried inserting "<2->" in several places, but nothing seems to work. Is there any smart solution?

Comment: There is always \raisebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be what you seek? Use \only<2-> to wrap the quation.

[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{VERY INTELLIGENT FRAME TITLE}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics<1->[scale=.23]{example-image-a}
\begin{center}
\tiny{\quad\qquad\text{VERY FAMOUS PAPER}}
\end{center}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\raisebox{15pt}{
\includegraphics<2->[scale=.23]{example-image-b}}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{.5cm}
\small
\only<2->{
\begin{align} \nonumber 
*EQUATION*
\end{align}
}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jesse instead of manualy computed `\raisebox` you can use `t` (top align) option in `columns` or every `column`: `\begin{columns}[t]` or `\begin{column}[t]{.5\textwidth}`